# Is the expression "To think you would stoop so low" often misused?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I found the following sentence in a fanfiction:

> To think you would stoop so low as to become that girl's second
>   husband.

I am thinking it's wrongly used, because the sentence is incomplete. What should the second part of the sentence look like? I am thinking there are multiple answers to this, could you give me a few example of how to complete this sentence. I am seeing people use the expression in a similar manner, but I feel it would only be correct if they put an ellipsis (...) after it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***[To think](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20think)*** in this context is an idiomatic expression used to express surprise or dismay and thus is not constrained by typical grammar rules about infinitives as subjects.

As a whole, [its meaning](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+think) is along the lines of

> "It's surprising that..." or
>
> "It's shameful that..."

It doesn't mean "Thinking that..." as it would in a sentence like 
"To think [that] the moon is made of cheese is incorrect."

Comment: Idioms don't necessarily need to be internally consistent or grammatical—but the sentences in which they are found (if they are not sentences themselves) should normally be grammatical. If used as a narrative sentence, this would be a sentence fragment and wouldn't be excused merely because it's an idiom. However, writing often *does* use ungrammatical sentences for stylistic effect. So, it might be fine in the right context. It would also be fine as a line of dialogue spoken by someone. There isn't enough context here to determine what the case is with this specific quotation.

Comment: @JasonBassford The quotation in the OP's question is a complete sentence and is grammatically correct - or is that not what you meant.  The full translation would be "It is shameful that you would become that girl's second husband."

Comment: No, the quotation is *not* a complete sentence. (Although your paraphrase of it is.) The sentence fragment *itself* is grammatically correct (or as an idiom it is irrelevant)—but, as a formal sentence in its entirety, it is not. (What I had meant is that it doesn't need to be a complete sentence in order to be used in some contexts.)